# Wso2 LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

So i am using Wso2 and when i try to create i get this error

`[LDAP: error code 65 - no structural object class provided]`

I also got some other mapping errors before that but after mapping correctly the Wso2 attributes to LDAP attributes they went away but now i am stuck on this error. From searching around i found that this error means  that the operation that i am trying to do is violating the object class rules for the entry.

How can i get more about what the violation is about so that i can do something about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling debug logs for user.core component. In `<product_home>/repository/conf/log4j.properties` file, uncomment the following entry and restart the server. Then add a user again and check the wso2carbon.log file.

```
#log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG
```

Comment: Well the logs are a bit more verbose now, but still i did not get any additional info on why the schema is violated.

Comment: is there a complete stack trace ? Also try adding the user from the admin management console an see whether you get the same error. If you can add user from the management console without an issue, the mapping issue should be due to one of the attributes sent with the SCIM request

Comment: Well i did over come this... it was a problem about attributes mapping. I had to change the mapping values to something else cause the ones that where assigned where giving some problems. But now i am experiencing some other issue of not having write permissions. will make a post about it

Comment: This is the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570195/wso2-user-creation-error-ldap-error-code-50-no-write-access-to-parent